# How do i get the URL from the html code? i just want the bold url as text

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
'''<img alt="Samsung Galaxy A10 6.2" 2="" gb="" 32="" nero"="" title="Samsung Galaxy A10 6.2" itemprop="image" data-module="overlay ajax" data-overlay-target="#modal-gallery" data-overlay-backdrop="true" data-ajax-target="#modal-gallery" data-ajax-istantload="false" data-ajax-url="/online/Smartphone/SM-A105FZKUITV-pidSAMA10/zoomImages" data-ajax-event="click" data-ajax-callback="initSliderZoom" **src="https://static2.unieuro.it/medias/sys_master/root/h74/h94/28339615629342/-img-gallery-71166825-7551572945.jpg"** class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 320px;" tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control10">'''
```

**src="https://static2.unieuro.it/medias/sys_master/root/h74/h94/28339615629342/-img-gallery-71166825-7551572945.jpg"**

i need to get the url as text 
i am using beautifulsoup and have the page saved to a variable as a soup object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so there is not enough info to start with but if you want to extract the `src` attribute from the above html, then you can do it like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page='''<img alt="Samsung Galaxy A10 6.2" 2="" gb="" 32="" nero"="" title="Samsung Galaxy A10 6.2" itemprop="image" data-module="overlay ajax" data-overlay-target="#modal-gallery" data-overlay-backdrop="true" data-ajax-target="#modal-gallery" data-ajax-istantload="false" data-ajax-url="/online/Smartphone/SM-A105FZKUITV-pidSAMA10/zoomImages" data-ajax-event="click" data-ajax-callback="initSliderZoom" src="https://static2.unieuro.it/medias/sys_master/root/h74/h94/28339615629342/-img-gallery-71166825-7551572945.jpg" class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 320px;" tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control10">'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
src_url=soup.find('img').get("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method with [`string.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find), but there is likely a better way to scrape it using BeautifulSoup:

```py
string = '''<img alt...'''

start = string.find('src="') + 5
url = string[ start : string[start:].find('"') + start ]

print(url)
> https://static2.unieuro.it/medias/sys_master/root/h74/h94/28339615629342/-img-gallery-71166825-7551572945.jpg
```

Comment: Note that `src='...'` and `src="..."` are both legal in HTML, anyways do not manually parse HTML using your own string methods as this is likely to end badly for some unforseen case like bad HTML ...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your html you have

```
**src=....
```

If you can change that to:

```
** src=....
```

then the following will work.

```js
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
console.log(img.src)
```

```html
<img alt="Samsung Galaxy A10 6.2" 2="" gb="" 32="" nero"="" title="Samsung Galaxy A10 6.2" itemprop="image" data-module="overlay ajax" data-overlay-target="#modal-gallery" data-overlay-backdrop="true" data-ajax-target="#modal-gallery" data-ajax-istantload="false" data-ajax-url="/online/Smartphone/SM-A105FZKUITV-pidSAMA10/zoomImages" data-ajax-event="click" data-ajax-callback="initSliderZoom" ** src="https://static2.unieuro.it/medias/sys_master/root/h74/h94/28339615629342/-img-gallery-71166825-7551572945.jpg"** class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 320px;" tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control10">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is correct, that is to say, there are two * in front of SRC, the following method is recommended to get the data. This library keeps the original data of XML without changing it intelligently.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<img alt="Samsung Galaxy A10 6.2" 2="" gb="" 32="" nero"="" title="Samsung Galaxy A10 6.2" itemprop="image" data-module="overlay ajax" data-overlay-target="#modal-gallery" data-overlay-backdrop="true" data-ajax-target="#modal-gallery" data-ajax-istantload="false" 
data-ajax-url="/online/Smartphone/SM-A105FZKUITV-pidSAMA10/zoomImages" data-ajax-event="click" data-ajax-callback="initSliderZoom" 
**src="https://static2.unieuro.it/medias/sys_master/root/h74/h94/28339615629342/-img-gallery-71166825-7551572945.jpg"** class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 320px;" tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control10">
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
img = doc.img
print (img["**src"])
```

Result:

```
https://static2.unieuro.it/medias/sys_master/root/h74/h94/28339615629342/-img-gallery-71166825-7551572945.jpg
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples/